# apache server not restarting in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu

When I am trying to restart the `apache2` services with `sudo service apache2 restart` command, I am getting this error.

> (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to
>   address [::]:80 (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could
>   not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available,
>   shutting down AH00015: Unable to open logs Action 'start' failed. The
>   Apache error log may have more information.

So I added `ServerName localhost` in my `apache2.conf` file and then tried to restart the `apache2` service. I am getting the same above error.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons why this problem exists:

**1. Multiple ‘Listen’ Directive Entries Existing in Configuration Files. (Solution below)**

Hit `grep Listen /etc/apache2/ports.conf`

Check if you are getting something like: 
Listen 80 
Listen 81 
Listen 80 
Listen 443 
Listen 443

The error log `could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80` mentions its an issue with the port 80. Hence edit the file and remove the duplicate.

**2.  Another Process is Already Using Port 80**

Hit : `fuser -n tcp 80` along with `ps aux | grep PID` or hit

```
ss -plnt sport eq :80
```

and kill the processes.

Comment: do you have it twice?

Comment: Okay, so here was the problem, I think It was because nginx was installed and it was not allowing to evem start the apache. I just removed nginx and apache restarted well

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a process that's still using it. You can do

```
pidof apache2
```

The last pid in the list is the main process you can kill.

or you can do

```
netstat -anp | grep :80 | grep -i listen
```

Then on the right hand side of the line, that it outputs you'll see the PID.

or you can do

```
lsof -i :80
```

Then the top apache process is the one you'll want to kill. Which is the number in the 2nd column output.

Then whenver you have the main pid from one of these commands use this.

`kill -9 <pid>` e.g. `kill -9 12345`

Comment: I killed with `kill -9 2905`, getting same error again

Comment: cd to `/etc/apache2` Then `grep -iR Listen` let me know if you get more than one Listen with 80

Comment: I am getting one `Listen` with 80 and two `Listen` 443.

Comment: Okay, so here was the problem, I think It was because nginx was installed and it was not allowing to evem start the apache. I just removed nginx and apache restarted well

Comment: yes i was going to ask you if some other app was using it. thats good then

Comment: Such a waste of time but worth the commands I got to know :)

Thanks

Comment: you cant run both but can be used as reverse proxy if you needed nginx but apache would be on another port